# sed to replace block of XML with another block (preserving new line breaks)

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have a XML file, that I'm trying to edit inplace using `sed` on a mac

Sample XML:

```
...
<clientSSLCertificatesConfiguration>
   <certificates>
      <clientCertificate>
        <certificate>
          <name>1234567</name>
          <storeAlias>cert_alias</storeAlias>
        </certificate>
      </clientCertificate>
    </certificates>
</clientSSLCertificatesConfiguration>
...
```

I'm trying to replace everything between `<certificates> .. </certificates>` using `sed`.

My replacement block is stored in a variable called `$CERT_UPDATE` looks like this:

```
<certificates>
    <clientCertificate>
     <certificate>
      <name>new_cert_name</name>
      <storeAlias>new_alias</storeAlias>
     </certificate>
    </clientCertificate>
</certificates>
```

So far, I've the following piece

```
sed -i -ne "/<certificates>/,/<\/certificates>/ {
    /<\/certificates>/ s@.*@$CERT_UPDATE@
    t
    d
}" my_file.xml
```

**There are some issues in my script:**

(1) The new line are not preserved in the file after replacement

(2) Rerunning the script deletes everything after `</certificates>`

(3) Running on online GNU `sed` tool works without error. However, running this on a mac I get `sed: 2: "/<certificates>/,/<\/ce ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern` error

Comment: You're dealing with xml, so you should use a proper xml parser to handle it: xmlstarlet or xidel, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach if your shell supports process substitution:

```
sed -i.backup -n '
/^[[:blank:]]*<certificates>/,/^[[:blank:]]*<\/certificates>/!{p;d;}
/^[[:blank:]]*<\/certificates>/!d
r '<(echo "$CERT_UPDATE") my_file.xml
```

Otherwise, you can write the contents of the variable `CERT_UPDATE` to a temporary file and replace the `<(echo "$CERT_UPDATE")` with the name of that temporary file.

Comment: @M._Nejat_Aydin I liked your solution.


Could you please explain `!{p;d;}` , and `!d`, and `r` ? 

I'd appreciate that

Comment: @Vab You may consider reading [Addresses overview](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses-overview.html#Addresses-overview) and [sed commands summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html#sed-commands-list)

Answer (score 1):

To modify the 2 fields with a dedicated XML tool such as
[xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) you can say,

```sh
test "${bettersorrythansafe}" || cp file.xml file.xml.was
xmlstarlet edit --inplace --omit-decl \
  --var T '//clientCertificate/certificate[name = "1234567"]' \
  -u '$T/name' -v 'new_cert_name' \
  -u '$T/storeAlias' -v 'new_alias' \
file.xml
```

... assuming namespaces agree.